# How to use "DataTable.Select(?)" in master-detail relationship

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable, relationship, master-detail

```
DataTable with Master Detail relationship in Dataset:

**product** 
--------------
product_id      (pK)
product_name       
product_price

**operator**
--------------
operator_id     (pK)   
operator_name

**machine**
--------------
machine_id      (pK)
product_id      (fK)
operator_id     (fK)


Contents of the DataTable is

**product** 
--------------
1   bag       20
2   shoe      15
3   clothes   30

**operator**
--------------
1   alex
2   bery

**machine**
--------------
1   1    1
2   2    2
```

I want to display the data as below using DataTable.Select(???) How? Thanks.

```
**machine**
--------------
1    bag    alex
2    shoe   bery
```

This program is running, only the resulting output is (1 1 1), I want output like this
(1 bag alex)

```
Dim dtTable As DataTable = MyDataset.Tables("machine")
Dim rowSearching() As DataRow

Try

   ' Problem in here... "dtTable.Select"
   rowSearching = dtTable.Select("Parent(fk_machine_product_id).product_id = product_id AND Parent(fk_machine_totalizer_id).totalizer_id = totalizer_id AND Parent(fk_machine_operator_id).operator_id = operator_id")

   If rowSearching.Length > 0 Then
      For Each dr As DataRow In rowSearching
        MessageBox.Show(CStr(dr.Item(0)) & " " & CStr(dr.Item(1)) & " " & CStr(dr.Item(2)))
      Next
   End If

Catch ex As Exception
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try


Thanks & Best Regard,
Dewi
```

Comment: Relationships in Datasets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbwcse3d(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

@magnus, I found a solution based on a your reference, Thanks.

I don't use "DataTable.Select (?)" but "GetParentRow". Details as follows, I will share may be useful for others. Thanks.

```
Dim childMachineDataTable As DataTable = MyDataset.Tables("machine")

Dim parentProductRow As DataRow = Nothing
Dim parentOperatorRow As DataRow = Nothing

Dim productName As New ArrayList
productName.Clear()

Dim operatorName As New ArrayList
operatorName.Clear()

For Each childRow As DataRow In childMachineDataTable.Rows
    parentProductRow = childRow.GetParentRow("fk_machine_product_id")
    parentOperatorRow = childRow.GetParentRow("fk_machine_operator_id")

    productName.Add(parentProductRow.Item(1))
    operatorName.Add(parentOperatorRow.Item(1))
Next

MessageBox.Show(CStr(productName.Item(0))  ' output: bag
MessageBox.Show(CStr(productName.Item(1))  ' output: shoe

MessageBox.Show(CStr(operatorName.Item(0)) ' output: alex
MessageBox.Show(CStr(operatorName.Item(1)) ' output: bary
```

Comment: It may be a better idea to just create an instance of `productName` and `operatorName` instead of executing `.Clear()` on them to create an instance. Then you also won't need to declare them using `New`.